# Unable to use good old JS function with some jQuery in Laravel 5.7 blade template with webpack - method not found

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, webpack

I'm using Laravel 5 Boilerplate that comes with some structure already done.

I want to call a simple JavaScript method from the blade. Here's what I did:

1) Created file called `test123.js`

content of `test123.js`:

```
function test123() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('hello from test123');
    });
}
```

2) I opened the existing `app.js` and added:

`import './test123';`

3) I called `npm dev run` - all green, all OK.

4) In blade `index.blade.php` I typed:

```
@push('after-scripts')
    <script>
        test123();
    </script>
@endpush
```

I went to compiled file:

```
<script src="http://foo.local/js/backend.js?id=8dbe74e012c3122422da"></script>
```

My method is there:

[image]

however it's not visible.

[image]

I guess it's about scopes? I don't want to make it window.test123. Should I? I just want define good old JS / jQuery method and invoke it only when needed in specific templates.

"Modern" JS is not my strong point as I find it very convoluted. I haven't touched default `webpack.mix.js`.

```
mix.setPublicPath('public');

mix.sass('resources/sass/frontend/app.scss', 'css/frontend.css')
    .sass('resources/sass/backend/app.scss', 'css/backend.css')
    .js('resources/js/frontend/app.js', 'js/frontend.js')
    .js([
        'resources/js/backend/before.js',
        'resources/js/backend/app.js',
        'resources/js/backend/after.js'
    ], 'js/backend.js')
    .extract([
        'jquery',
        'bootstrap',
        'popper.js/dist/umd/popper',
        'axios',
        'sweetalert2',
        'lodash',
        '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core',
        '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons',
        '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons',
        '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
    ]);
```

Please help me to achieve this simple thing. I know the solution probably is not difficult but I don't know what to do…

Thank you.

Edit 1: I almost forgot. Here's the [Boilerplate](https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate) structure:

[image]

Edit 2: User **brk** requested some more screenshots:

[image]

Comment: can you show dom from developer's tool

Comment: Hi @brk, I uploaded the screenshot at the very bottom of the question. What I want to achieve is to move all that jQuery stuff into the `test123` and reuse it in more templates. This is what I really want to achieve. So far I cannot event call the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the function explicitly:

```
export function test123() {...}
```

and later import it:

```
import 'test123' from './test123';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try do this with require.js

```
 //declare fn test123
 test123(){ ...do something}
 module.exports.test123 = test123;
```

and then

```
 let test123 = require('./test123');
```

Here you can find more information about using require.js in browser with jquery https://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html